# how to trying to write workflow-If picklist value is A & changes to B - send email

Tags: community, workflow, sandbox, lightning-experience

If FIELD NAME = “step1,”  “step2,” or “step3”  and the value changes to either “step1” became to step3 then send Email.

If FIELD NAME = “step1,”  “step2,” or “step3”  and the value changes to either “step3,”to "step1" then send Email #2.

we need to create workflow and specify two condition .
1) user change step 1 to step 3 then send email in show message "step forward".
2) user change step 4 to step 2 then send email in show message "step backward".

Comment: Do you have your values ending with numbers like in your example or they are only letters? And is this a picklist field?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: hi picklist values is step1 and step2----step 10.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can achieve it through process builder.

Ischange, Priorvalue and ispickval

It's like  Ischange( fieldname__C) && priorvalue("fieldname__C")= " Step 1" && ispickval( fieldname__C)," step 2"

step forward email trigger.

for backward priorvalue  (fieldname__C) should not equal to forward step.